Finding twice-differentiable $f$ such that $f(x) = x^{-a} - 1 + f(1) + f'(1)(x-1)$
$a$ is a constant, $x \in (0,\infty)$. I encountered this differential equation playing around with some material, unsure if it hides something interesting.
In fact, plugging $f(1)$ returns an identity, making me think that $f(x)=x^{-a} - 1$ would suffice.
However: $f'(x) = -ax^{-a-1} + f'(1) \rightarrow f'(1) = -a + f'(1)$
Which sends me back to the start.
It is somewhat similar to solving for $f$ given the reminder of its Taylor series after the first order.

What your last line shows is that there is no solution if $a \neq 0$.

This would be on $(0, \infty)$ or what?

Yes indeed in $(0, \infty)$
